# Spring Boot Application can not inject Bean from another module

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have the following 3 modules in my spring-boot application:

- web (Entry point / Main Application class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`
- persistence
- service

I'm now trying to inject a service in the `web` module which comes from the `service`. In the service I'm injecting the repository which comes from the `persistence` module. When I start the application the following error shows up:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.project.service.images.ImageService required a bean of type 'com.project.persistence.repositories.ImageRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.project.persistence.repositories.ImageRepository' in your configuration.
```

`ImageService` class:

```java
package com.project.service.images;

import com.project.common.entities.Image;
import com.project.persistence.repositories.ImageRepository;
import com.project.service.AbstractService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

@Component
public class ImageService extends AbstractService {

    private final ImageRepository imageRepository;

    @Autowired
    public ImageService(ImageRepository imageRepository) {
        this.imageRepository = imageRepository;
    }

    public Image getImage(Long id) {
        return imageRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(EntityNotFoundException::new);
    }

    public List<Image> getAll() {
        return imageRepository.findAll();
    }

    public List<Image> getAll(Date from) {
        return imageRepository.findByDateRange(from, null);
    }

    public List<Image> getAll(Date from, Date to) {
        return imageRepository.findByDateRange(from, to);
    }

    public List<Image> getAllForDay(Date day) {
        return imageRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

`ImageRepository` class:

```java
package com.project.persistence.repositories;

import com.project.common.entities.Image;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface ImageRepository extends JpaRepository<Image, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT i FROM Image i WHERE i.created > :from AND i.created < :to")
    public List<Image> findByDateRange(@Param("from") Date from, @Param("to") Date to);
}
```

And that's how I inject the service into my class in the `web` module:

```java
@Autowired
private ImageService imageService;
```

So on I was searching throught the internet and saw some people with similar problems. Then I got the tip that I should add the `scanBasePackages` to the `SpringBootApplication` annotation at my application class. So I did this:

```java
package com.project.web;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.project.service")
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

But it's still not working. If I add the specific package for scanning to the annotation `com.project.service.images` the injection of the `ImageService` works but then it can't find the `ImageRepository` in it.

What am I doing wrong?

I know that so many modules doesn't make sense for such a small application but I have to because it's for my apprenticeship and we need to make multiple modules.

Comment: In which package you Application class exists.

Comment: @Gundamaiah `com.project.web`

Comment: it is considered a good practice to store application class inside of root package of the project - you won't need any annotation since "@SpringBootApplication" already contains "@ComponentScan" which would scan "com.project" package and its subpackages for components

Comment: @mangusta So I need to add the Application class into the parent POM under `com.project`?

Comment: Also you can use componenscan annotation and you can give package names. Don't forget to add repository module to main module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What normally should do is to have this structure in your app

```
app
   SpringBootApp.java
   app.repositories
       Repository.java
   app.services
       Service.java
```

If you are not following that package structure, then you need to have

```
@EnableJpaRepositories
```

And watch out for your entities which may have the same issue, in that case take a look at:

```
@EntityScan
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try to change scanBasePackages to "com.project". Repository is in a different package.

eg:

`@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.project")`

Comment: Did You add `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation? if not, try it

Comment: Yes, I've added the `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.project")` and the `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation to my `Application` class and I still get the same error..

Answer (score 0):

Spring is not able to scan your repository class as it resides in different package.

As per your response in comments, your Application class in under

> com.project.web

, so by default Spring will scan all classes under this packages and subpackages. So you need to put all your spring components under the same package/sub package where your application resides.

Answer (score -1):

Create a config class , and define all you beans in that one location , in this case you need the bean for ImageRepository, Something like...

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class Config {
    @Bean
    public ImageRepository getImageRepository() {
        // return the image repository object
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that's not possible with Spring JPA Repositories.

Comment: This is not possible as spring will abstracts and  internally handles the implementation of repositories.